Need to list an app in the Security & Privacy Settings in MacOS
This app EOSUtility from Canon is not getting listed in the 'Security & Privacy' setting of System Preferences in MacOS.
I am on MacbookAir with M1 chip having MacOS BigSur(11.5)
This app EOSUtility has been downloaded directly from internet.

What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this so far? Also, are you running the latest version of MacOS supported on this hardware?
